# add content with view pager

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a viewpager, but the problem is that I need to add some data which I am getting from API to be shown on page 0 of viewpager.Here's the code:

```
 self.dataSource = self;
 self.delegate = self;
 [self loadData];

-(void)loadData{
     //all content is received here
}

- (UIViewController *)viewPager:(ViewPagerController *)viewPager contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
UIViewController *cvc;
switch (index){

    case 0:
        //I need the data here
        break;
    case 1:
         break;
    case 2:
        break;
}
  return cvc;
}
```

I am not sure where to call the load method. I tried calling the delegate methods within the load method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call Delegate method after receiving response from API end.

Comment: tried that...the view pager's tab disappears doing so.

Comment: Okh, also try this after Response,
 self.dataSource = self;
 self.delegate = self;
 [self loadData];